# Migrating firebase project to another firebase project with a different region

Tags: firebase

Today I discovered that it is not possible to change region in firebase project once it has been created.

When I initially created my project it was set up to use us multiregion option and I now need to move it to a single region instance in europe.

It seems that only option here is to create new firebase project in that region and migrate the data.

Migrating database data is straight forward via admin sdk, but how about things like custom domains set up for hosting and dynamic links, also email? Certificates for push notifications etc... Does all of this require manual migration as well, or can it be automated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to move any part from one Firebase project to another automatically. You might be able to automate part of it through the [project management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.projectManagement), but definitely not all of it.